# Clear material for UV Box

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I have constructed an UV light box using the innards of a commercially available finger nail drying unit consisting of 4* 9w tubes. (should be more than enough). I have had very poor results in exposing both pre coated and DIY board. My question is - 
Is 10mm thick polycarbonate too thick to transmit sufficient UV or should I be using Acrylic sheet or glass?

Comment: Ordinary window glass works very well for me. It has good transmittivity for the wavelength used for PCB exposure.

Answer (score 6):

Polycarbonate is almost perfectly opaque to UV, so it's no wonder your setup isn't working. You can get special UV Transparent  (UVT) plexiglass, which will gain you energy in the 300 - 400 nm (long-wave). http://www.plasticgenius.com/2011/05/infrared-and-ultraviolet-transmission.html

You really need to find a data sheet for your resist, and see what wavelengths are required.

I would recommend that you don't use a plate for support of your board. Rather, make an adjustable framework which will just contact the board corners, and support the board that way.

And I agree that I'm not being helpful, but I can't resist (get it?) pointing out that sapphire will work excellently for your application. http://www.valleydesign.com/sapppic.htm

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - but not for the sapphire?

Comment: I have seen a 300mm+ single crystal sapphire boule, so maybe for the wealthy hobbyist needing modest board sizes..

Answer (score 4):

Plastics degrade with UV exposure so they tend to have UV absorbing additives that will scupper your plans.

Ordinary soda lime window glass works okay for longer UV wavelengths. Use as thin a piece as practical.

The ideal material is fused silica or quartz glass but it's probably not easily available or affordable. It will transmit even UV-C germicidal light.

Answer (score 3):

We used to make our own PC Boards using Dupont Riston dry-laminate film.  This process worked extremely well and we used it for years until a commercial supplier of prototype circuit boards became available (AP Circuits in Calgary, Canada).

Shameless plug: [AP Circuits](http://www.apcircuits.com/) ships world-wide.  Get your board files to them before 11:00 AM MST and finished boards are shipped via FedEx at noon (MST) the following day.

Our expose lamp started off being a short-arc Xenon lamp but we later changed to mercury-vapour lamp.  This would be very similar to the lamp that you are using but ours was much larger - 175 Watts instead of your 9W tube.

The negative film was held in contact with the sensitized circuit board with a vacuum frame made from ordinary window glass.  I have no idea what the UV transmission properties of this glass is - we simply adjusted the expose time until we achieved proper results.

To do this, we obtained a commercial expose-time calculator film.  This is a simple piece of film that has several identical targets on it, with each target having a different piece of neutral-density filter over top of targets.  You would expose your test board for double the normal expose time using this film.  You would then choose the best target after developing and etching the test board and apply that multiplier factor to your doubled expose time to end up with the new best time.

It is now apparently possible to make your own exposure time test film.  One such is available at [SCREEN PRINTING EXPOSURE CALCULATOR](http://www.anthemprintingsf.com/Screen-Exposure-Calculator-s/216.htm).  This is somewhat different from what we used but it may work well for you.  It appears that there are several such DIY exposure-time calculators available.

For what it's worth, our tests showed that we were able to achieve approximately 100 micron resolution with our circuit board process.  This amazing result was due to both scrupulous board prep (physical cleaning, chemical cleaning, pre-etch) and the absolutely-fabulous Dupont Riston dry-laminate film.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [polycarbonate](http://www.opticampus.com/tools/transmittance.php?number=0) isn't a good choice no matter what.

Also, check [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=polycarbonate%20spectral%20transmission&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=rleiVdrgPImvoQTA9Y-4CQ&ved=0CCMQsAQ&biw=1024&bih=677) out.